# Mensagem de erro em campo datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho um campo em minha aplicação em mvc asp.net c# para colocar data inicial e data final.

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A data de início é obrigatória")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime DataInicio { get; set; }
```

Porém, enquanto o usuário está digitando a data aparece embaixo do campo uma mensagem em vermelho:

> The field  must be a date.

Eu não implementei isso, não sei de onde surge. Alguém sabe como desaparecer com esse alerta?

View

```
@model Competências.Models.Experiencia

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/validation")

@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions
                {
                    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                    HttpMethod = "POST"
                }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<div class="modal-body row">
    <div class="col-md-7">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nome)
       @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Nome, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nome)
    </div>
      <div class="col-md-5">
       @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Funcao)
       @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Funcao, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Funcao)
    </div>

</div>
    <div class="modal-body row">

    <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DataInicio)   
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataInicio, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataInicio)
    </div> 

    <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DataFinal)       
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataFinal, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataFinal)
    </div>


    </div>

<div class="modal-footer">

    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Salvar" />
    <a class="btn btn-default" onclick="FechaModal();">Cancelar</a>
</div>


}
```

Input gerado no browser

```
<div class="modal-body row">

    <div class="col-md-4">

         <b>Data de Início</b> 
        <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-date="O campo DataInicio deve ser uma data." data-val-required="A data de início é obrigatória" id="DataInicio" name="DataInicio" type="date" value="">
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="DataInicio" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div> 

    <div class="col-md-4">

        <b>Data Final</b>
        <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-date="O campo DataFinal deve ser uma data." data-val-required="A data de início é obrigatória" id="DataFinal" name="DataFinal" type="datetime" value="">
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="DataFinal" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3">



</div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Você instalou o `jquery-validate`, o `globalize` e o `jquery.globalize` no seu projeto?

Comment: Peguei o projeto já iniciado, não sei te dizer. Como verifico isso? Preciso instalar ou desinstalar?

Comment: Vou te passar um roteirinho.

Comment: Qual o código do arquivo `Shared/EditorTemplates/DateTime.cshtml`?  

Qual o HTML gerado na sua view? `<input ... >`

Comment: Coloca como que ta o código do input em que precisa declarar a data pra gente ver e sua pergunta fica mais clara !

Answer (score 16):

O problema acontece porque um projeto ASP.NET MVC vem configurado com a cultura `en-US` por padrão. Essa mensagem de validação é feita pelo *jQuery* usando *Unobtrusive Ajax* e *Validation*, que precisam ser acoplados a um plugin de globalização para funcionar corretamente.

### Passo 1: Instalar os pacotes de Globalização

No Visual Studio, vá em <kbd>View</kbd> > <kbd>Other Windows</kbd> > <kbd>Package Manager Console</kbd>.

Instale os seguintes pacotes, usando os comandos abaixo:

> PM> Install-Package jQuery.Validation.Globalize
>
> PM> Install-Package jquery-globalize

### Passo 2: Configurar Web.config para usar configurações em Português

Adicione o seguinte no seu `web.config`:

```
<configuration>
    <globalization uiCulture="pt-BR" culture="pt-BR" enableClientBasedCulture="true" requestEncoding="UTF-8" responseEncoding="UTF-8" fileEncoding="UTF-8" />
</configuration>
```

`pt-PT` também funciona, se for do desejo do programador usar a cultura em português de Portugal.

### Passo 3: Configurar Bundles

Verifique no seu arquivo **App_Start/BundleConfig.cs** se existem os seguintes Bundles registrados:

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.replace-text.js"));

        var bundle = new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval") { Orderer = new AsIsBundleOrderer() };

        bundle
            .Include("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")
            .Include("~/Scripts/jquery.validate-vsdoc.js")
            .Include("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")
            .Include("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")
            .Include("~/Scripts/globalize/globalize.js")
            .Include("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.globalize.js");
        bundles.Add(bundle);
    }
}
```

**Bundles** são porções de código que o ASP.NET MVC monta para você. Em ambiente de desenvolvimento você pode ler os fontes originais. Ao publicar seu site, os códigos contidos dentro de *Bundles* são minificados automaticamente.

`AsIsBundleOrderer` é um ordenador de arquivos do *Bundle*. É usado porque, [conforme expliquei aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/60423/problema-de-data-com-globalize-js-e-jquery-validation-globalize-js-como-resolve/60432#60432), a ordem de inclusão dos scripts não é respeitada, e para este caso é preciso ter uma ordem de aparição desses scripts. Sua implementação está a seguir.

```
public class AsIsBundleOrderer : IBundleOrderer
{
    public IEnumerable<BundleFile> OrderFiles(BundleContext context, IEnumerable<BundleFile> files)
    {
        return files;
    }
}
```

### Passo 4: Configurar Layout das Views

Verifique se estes Bundles estão no arquivo **Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    ...

    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Seu site</title>
    ...

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    ...
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    @Flash.FlashMessage(TempData)
</head>
```

Os lugares onde coloquei reticências normalmente possuem mais código. Procure manter a ordem dos *Bundles* acima, porque a ordem é fundamental para o funcionamento da globalização.

Assim você não precisa alterar nada do que foi feito e as validações de datas vão funcionar normalmente.

Comment: Ou usar `$('#data').removeAttr("data-val-date");`

Comment: Essa referência está incorreta: .Include("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobstrusive.js"). O certo seria: .Include("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")

Answer (score 6):

Quatro soluções:

### Retirando o ValidationMessageFor

Na sua view, logo abaixo do seu

```
@Html.EditorFor(...)
```

Deve ter um código assim:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataInicio)
```

É este código que gera a validação que você está vendo.

### Definindo um valor padrão para o campo

Agora a solução talvez não seja tirar esta validação e sim tratar.
Uma sugestão que te dou é preencher esta data automaticamente no seu Controller.

### Verificar mensagem após a digitação da data

Já verificou se depois de digitar a data toda se a mensagem desaparece? Pode ser que a mensagem seja mostrada apenas enquanto esteja digitando a data.

### Traduzindo a Mensagem

Outra solução é traduzir a mensagem, [neste artigo da MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg674880%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) voce pode ver como fazer.

### Atualização

Tente utilizar a formatação assim:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
```

ou seja, tire o `ApplyFormatInEditMode = true`

Particularmente eu utilizo apenas o Atributo `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` não utilizo o `DisplayFormat`.

Comment: Segui o roteiro que você passou @Cigano Morrison Mendez e a mensagem foi traduzida para português, mas continua aparecendo.

Comment: E sim, @Renatto Machado, a mensagem aparece quando eu estou digitando a data. Assim que acabo de digitar a data corretamente ela desaparece. Eu queria que ela nunca chegasse a aparecer. Que só aparecesse a mensagem que especifiquei no meu Model "A data de início é obrigatória" quando o usuário tentasse salvar sem preencher o campo data.

Comment: @Renato Machado, quando eu uso o [DataType(DataType.Date)], só de selecionar a data, nenhuma mensagem aparece. Mas assim que eu clico em outro campo para dar sequencia no preenchimento do formulário, a mensagem da data aparece abaixo do campo e fica lá até eu salvar.

Comment: @kLucas vi aqui. Essa mensagem aparece porque voce está utilizando `Ajax.BeginForm`, por isso ele valida ainda enquanto está digitando. Tente fazer o que te falei no meu último comentário ai.

Comment: @kLucas este formulário seu tem que ser mesmo Ajax? Se não houver necessidade utilize `Html.BeginForm`.

Comment: Mas não deve ser isso @Renatto Machado. Pq tenho outro formulário que não estou usando ajax, estou usando: using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) e acontece a mesma coisa quando começo a preencher a data

Comment: eu comentei o Scripts.Render("~/bundles/validation") e não aparece a mensagem quando estou digitando a data. Em compensação não aparece nenhuma mensagem de erro quando eu tento salvar o formulário deixando os outros campos em branco. Os scripts que estão nele, estão acima

Comment: @kLucas no lugar do seu código aonde voce tem a mensagem: `"O campo DataInicio deve ser uma data."` deixe apenas `""`, creio que ela esteja no seu Model.

Comment: Mas é aí que tá @Renatto Machado! Não tem essa frase no meu projeto. Já fiz uma busca com as palavras em todo projeto e não tem isso. A mensagem do meu model é aquela que coloquei ali em cima: "A data de início é obrigatória" Não sei de onde sai essa mensagem, provavelmente um script já pronto que vem automaticamente

Answer (score 3):

Tive um problema recentemente assim com o navegador Chrome e resolvi colocando este código:

```
$.validator.addMethod('date',
        function (value, element, params) {
            if (this.optional(element)) {
                return true;
            }

var result = true;
            try{
                $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', value);
            } catch (e) {
                    result = false;
            }

            return result;
        }
)
```

Comment: Por favor, abra outra pergunta com sua dúvida. Não use o espaço de resposta para perguntar, mesmo que sua pergunta seja semelhante.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Penso que ele está a responder.

Comment: Concordo com @ramaral por causa da frase `resolvi colocando este código`.

Comment: Agora sim está ok.

Answer (score 3):

A única coisa que funcionou para minhas data em formato `dd/mm/yyyy` foi:

//Corrige o BUG de validação do chrome  do campo Date no formato dd/mm/yyyy

//fonte https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18546971/mvc-4-how-to-validate-a-non-us-date-with-client-validation

jQuery.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || moment(value, "DD/MM/YYYY", true).isValid();
};