# Problema de data com globalize.js e jquery.validation.globalize.js. Como resolver?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, jquery-validate

Estou tendo problemas com os campos data de minha aplicação.

[image: Campos data]

Seguinda essa resposta que me pareceu mais adequada, **[Mensagem de erro em campo datetime](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23251/mensagem-de-erro-em-campo-datetime/23260#23260)**, configurei minha aplicação ASP.NET MVC da seguinte forma:

1. Instalei o pacote jquery-globalize via `Install-Package jquery-globalize`;
2. Instalei o pacote jquery.validation.globalize via `Install-Package jquery.validation.globalize`;

   [image: estrutura dos arquivos estáticos]
3. Adicionei a tab no **Web.config** referênte ao idioma ***pt-BR***.

   ```
   <system.web>
       ...
       <globalization uiCulture="pt-BR" culture="pt-BR" enableClientBasedCulture="true"
           requestEncoding="UTF-8" responseEncoding="UTF-8" fileEncoding="UTF-8" />
       ...
   </system.web>
   ```

> Apesar de na resposta indica para adicionar em `<configuration>`, a aplicação acusava erro no arquivo Web.config e então consegui na tag `<system.web>`.

4. Configurei meu **BundleConfig.cs**:

   [image: BundleConfig.cs]
5. Organizei meus scripts conforme o exemplo da resposta, deixando assim:

   [image: scripts]

   O script com `Globalize.culture("pt-BR");` ao final da imagem foi uma última tentativa que fiz.
    O jquery.validation.js carrego pelas outras views, quando preciso, via `@section footerSection{ Scripts.Render("~/js/jqueryval"); }`.
    Então, meu output dos scripts ficam assim, em modo debug:

   [image: ordem dos scripts em output - modo debug]
6. Assim estão as propriedades de minha View Model utilizada para renderizar os campos:

   ```
   [DataType(DataType.Date)]
   [DisplayName("Data Vencto.")]
   [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe o campo {0}")]
   [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
   public DateTime? txtDataVencimento { get; set; }

   [DataType(DataType.Date)]
   [DisplayName("Data Pagto.")]
   [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe o campo {0}")]
   [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
   public DateTime? txtDataPagamento { get; set; }
   ```

   Já testei com `DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"`, mas também não funcionou.
7. Razor:

   ```
   <div class="form-group">
       @Html.LabelFor(model => model.txtDataVencimento, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
       <div class="col-md-10">
           @Html.EditorFor(model => model.txtDataVencimento, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.txtDataVencimento, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
       </div>
   </div>

   <div class="form-group">
       @Html.LabelFor(model => model.txtDataPagamento, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
       <div class="col-md-10">
           @Html.EditorFor(model => model.txtDataPagamento, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.txtDataPagamento, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
       </div>
   </div>
   ```

**Então lhes peço por ajuda: O que pode ainda estar faltando ou estar errado?**

---

## EDIÇÃO

Conforme a resposta do **Cigano Morrison**, a ordem dos meus scripts deveria ser outra e então apliquei o Bundle conforme orientação dada.

```
var bundle = new ScriptBundle("~/js/jqueryval") { Orderer = new AsIsBundleOrderer() };
bundle
    .Include("~/Static/js/jquery.validate.js")
    .Include("~/Static/js/jquery.validate.unobstrusive.js")
    .Include("~/Static/js/globalize/globalize.js")
    .Include("~/Static/js/jquery.validate.globalize.js");
bundles.Add(bundle);
```

Com isso meus scripts ficaram na ordem indicada:

[image: Nova ordem dos scripts]

Porém, ainda assim o erro continua, mas demonstrando mensagem em inglês: "**Please enter a valid date.**"

[image: Nova mensagem de erro]

Que ficou em negrito, na cor preta.

---

## EDIÇÃO

Ao editar meus bundles para que ficassem dessa forma:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/js/jquery").Include(
        "~/Static/js/jquery-{version}.js",
        "~/Static/js/jquery.plugin.js"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/js/jqueryval").Include(
        "~/Static/js/jquery.validate.js",
        "~/Static/js/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js",
        "~/Static/js/globalize/globalize.js",
        "~/Static/js/jquery.validate.globalize.js"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/js/bootstrap").Include(
        "~/Static/js/bootstrap.js"));


    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Static/css/styles").Include(
        "~/Static/css/bootstrap.css",
        "~/Static/css/site.css"));
}
```

E com a ordenação padrão feita pelo BundleConfig, meus scripts ficaram nessa ordem:

[image: Outra ordem dos scripts]

A validação de data passou, mas a de valores passou a dar errado:

[image: outra validação com a nova ordem dos scripts]

Comment: Olá, você esqueceu implementar arquivo CLDR, pois o globalize depende dele. Mais informações: http://cldr.unicode.org/, fiz um pequeno tutorial aqui : https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/227756/54019

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Este não é um problema simples (me consumiu na verdade o esforço de uma noite pra descobrir). O problema é a ordem dos js que precisa ser respeitada:

1. `jquery.validate.js`;
2. `jquery.validate.unobstrusive.js`;
3. `globalize/globalize.js`;
4. `jquery.validate.globalize.js`.

Só que a implementação padrão do [`ScriptBundle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.optimization.scriptbundle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) reordena mesmo com a ordem especificada corretamente no `Bundle`.

O jeito é implementar um `Bundle` que fique na ordem:

```
public class AsIsBundleOrderer : IBundleOrderer
{
    public IEnumerable<BundleFile> OrderFiles(BundleContext context, IEnumerable<BundleFile> files)
    {
        return files;
    }
}
```

E depois:

```
        var bundle = new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval") { Orderer = new AsIsBundleOrderer() };

        bundle
            .Include("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")
            .Include("~/Scripts/jquery.validate-vsdoc.js")
            .Include("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")
            .Include("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobstrusive.js")
            .Include("~/Scripts/globalize/globalize.js")
            .Include("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.globalize.js");
        bundles.Add(bundle);
```

---

**EDIT**

No caso dos números, é preciso trabalhar um pouco o validador numérico, que por algum motivo não está aceitando vírgula:

```
// Esta parte pode ser colocada em um script da aplicação e juntado ao Bundle
jQuery.validator.addMethod("mynumber", function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^(\d+|\d+,\d{1,2})$/.test(value);
}, "O campo " + element + " deve ser um número.");

// Esta parte é para cada form
$("#meuForm").validate({
    rules: {
        field: {
            required: true,
            mynumber: true
        }
    }
});
```

Ou como o autor da pergunta sugeriu, [usar o exemplo do Cleyton Ferrari](https://github.com/cleytonferrari/DataMoedaEmMVC4), que é mais ou menos a mesma coisa.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda! Implementei seu modelo para o Bundle e consegui a ordem dos scripts como você disse. Porém continua dando o mesmo erro. A diferença é que está em inglês: **`Please enter a valid date.`**. Vou editar minha pergunta com essas informações.

Comment: Edições feitas. A última eu achei interessante.

Comment: @Severo Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: Para não ter que escrever mais scripts para meus forms eu decidi por usar o ***methods_pt-BR.js*** como encontrado na web mas somente para number, pois com o data também o problema das datas voltou a ocorrer. Mas enfim, problema resolvido. Grato!

Comment: @Severo Pode por favor me passar o link dele pra eu atualizar a resposta?

Comment: Em vários sites eu já cheguei a achar esse plugin, mas aqui tem um exemplo dele: **[cleytonferrari](http://cleytonferrari.com/validacao-de-data-e-moeda-asp-net-mvc-jquery-validation-em-portugues/)**, ártigo na **[TechNet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7149.asp-net-mvc-globalizando-aplicacoes-pt-br.aspx)**.