# ASP.NET MVC input number

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, globalização

Estou tentando usar um `input` com `type=number`, porém no Chrome está dando que o valor informado deve ser um número.

O problema está no model state que está retornando inválido, pois ao dar o post, está entrando no Create.

Já implementei o globalize como nessa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/60423/problema-de-data-com-globalize-js-e-jquery-validation-globalize-js-como-resolve/60432#60432), porém não resolveu o caso.

Minha view

```
@model WebApplication24.Models.Produto

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Produto</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Descricao, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Descricao, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Descricao, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Valor, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">                
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Valor, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type = "number", @step = "any" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Valor, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Quantidade, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Quantidade, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type = "number", @step = "any" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Quantidade, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ValorCusto, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ValorCusto, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type = "number", @step = "any" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ValorCusto, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script type="text/javascript">

    </script>
}
```

Meu bundle

```
 var bundle = new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval") { Orderer = new AsIsBundleOrderer() };

            bundle
                .Include("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")
                .Include("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")
                .Include("~/Scripts/globalize.js")
                .Include("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.globalize.js")
                .Include("~/Scripts/methods_pt.js");
            bundles.Add(bundle);
```

methods_pt

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.methods, {    
    number: function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})+)(?:,\d+)?$/.test(value);
    }
});
```

Pacotes instalados

> Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.pt-br version="5.2.3"
>
> jQuery.Validation.Globalize version="1.1.0"
>
> jquery-globalize" version="1.1.1"

--

> Editei o código da view realizando as sugestões do Márcio, mas mesmo assim continua dizendo que o valor informado não é válido
> [image: Erro]

Adicionei os códigos do exemplo ao meu [GitHub](https://github.com/pablotdv/StackOverflow/tree/master/AspNetMvcInputTypeNumber)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dei uma olhada no seu código, para corrigir altere seu arquivo methods_pt.js para o seguinte código.

```
$.validator.methods.range = function (value, element, param) {
  var globalizedValue = value.replace(".", "");
  globalizedValue = globalizedValue.replace(",", ".");
  return this.optional(element) ||
    (globalizedValue >= param[0] &&
     globalizedValue <= param[1]);
};

$.validator.methods.number = function (value, element) {
  return this.optional(element) ||
    /^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:[\s\.,]\d{3})+)(?:[\.,]\d+)?$/
        .test(value);
};
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que você não tenha colocado um atributo necessário (acredito que só no chrome) do comportamento dos passos (step). Como terá numeros decimais, o chrome entende que 1 não é igual a 0.1, obviamente. então coloque como atributo o step="any" para todos os campos number

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.number_value, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type = "number", @step = "any" } })
```

e se necessário um MIN e um MAX;

Answer (score 0):

Acho que você precisa mudar a configuração do Globalization no web.config da aplicação, para que o modelBinder funcione corretamente, procure pela tag

```
<configuration>
...
   <system.web>
   ...
      <globalization culture="pt-BR" uiCulture="pt-BR" />
```

[Fonte](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx)

[Fonte 2](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7149.asp-net-mvc-globalizando-aplicacoes-pt-br.aspx)

Comment: já está dessa forma o meu web.config

Comment: No seu modelo, os campos são Double?

Comment: São decimal, postei na pergunta o link pra download do projeto

Comment: @PabloVargas, olhei o projeto e não achei nenhum problema. Acho que então você vai precisar implementar O Binder, e adicionar ele no Global.asax, segue um link de exemplo: http://www.devmedia.com.br/asp-net-mvc-manipulando-valores-monetarios/28907

Answer (score 0):

Crie um arquivo .js com o seguinte trecho de código.

```
(function ($) {
    $.validator.methods.range = function (value, element, param) {
        var globalizedValue = value.replace(",", ".");
        return this.optional(element) || (globalizedValue >= param[0] && 
        globalizedValue <= param[1]);
};

$.validator.methods.number = function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:[\s\.,]\d{3})+)(?:
    [\.,]\d+)?$/.test(value);
};

//Date dd/MM/yyyy
$.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
    var date = value.split("/");
    return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(date[2], date[1], date[0]).toString());
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Referencie este arquivo depois do arquivo jqueryvalidate.js, assim sobre escrevendo o método original.