# MVC 5 Validação pt-BR lado do cliente

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Estou com dificuldades em realizar a validação de datas e números no lado do cliente utilizando MVC 5 asp.net. Exemplos e tutoriais que encontro na internet estão todos desatualizados.

Realizei as modificações conforme esta [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43346928/how-to-enealbe-jquery-validation-localization-in-razor-file-asp-net-mvc-5-jqu) e a validação começou a funcionar corretamente em português, porém passou a ocorrer no lado do **lado do servidor**.

Instalei os dois pacotes:

1. jquery-globalize
2. jquery.validation.globalize

Na minha página inclui estas 4 referências:

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobstrusive.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/globalize.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.globalize.js")
}
```

E no web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <!-- outros parametros -->
    <globalization culture="pt-BR" uiCulture="pt-BR" />
</system.web>
```

obs: estou seguindo este tutorial [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/examining-the-edit-methods-and-edit-view)

Alguém teria algum exemplo mais completo, ou poderia me explicar o que está faltando?

Comment: Bruno, tem uma resposta relacionada [Aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/60423/problema-de-data-com-globalize-js-e-jquery-validation-globalize-js-como-resolve). Talvez o ajude na implementação.

Comment: Olá. Existe uma sequência ao qual os scripts devem respeitar.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Problema de data com globalize.js e jquery.validation.globalize.js. Como resolver?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/60423/problema-de-data-com-globalize-js-e-jquery-validation-globalize-js-como-resolve)

Answer (score 1):

Funciona. Bastar alterar o código no arquivo `BundleConfig`, além de adicionar os arquivos `methods_pt` e `helper.js`

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*",
                        "~/Scripts/methods_pt.js",
                        "~/Scripts/helper.js"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você deve respeitar está sequência:

1 - jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js // Se possuir Ajax

2 - jquery.validate.js

3 - jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js

4 - globalize.js

5 - jquery.validate.globalize.js

6 - methods-pt.js // **Esse você vai criar e inserir por penúltimo**

7 - helper.js // **Essa você vai criar e inserir por último**

Adicione o seguinte código no methods-pt.js

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.methods, {
    date: function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^\d\d?\/\d\d?\/\d\d\d?\d?$/.test(value);
    },
    number: function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})+)(?:,\d+)?$/.test(value);
    }
});
```

Adicione o seguinte código no helper.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //Filtro Decimal para aceitar vírgula
    $.validator.methods.range = function (value, element, param) {
        var globalizedValue = value.replace(",", ".");
        return this.optional(element) || (globalizedValue >= param[0] && globalizedValue <= param[1]);
    }

    $.validator.methods.number = function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:[\s\.,]\d{3})+)(?:[\.,]\d+)?$/.test(value);
    }
});
```