# Problemas com Data e Globalize

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Ao realizar o submit em um formulário com uma data dd/MM/yyyy, o valor é convertido para o formato americano no controller, ficando MM/dd/yyyy. Através da resposta [desta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23251/mensagem-de-erro-em-campo-datetime), configurei o globalize para solucionar este problema. Contudo, o erro persiste.

Segue abaixo bundle configurado:

```
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.globalize.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/globalize").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/globalize.js"));
```

Código para carregar os bundles

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/globalize")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

Linha de configuração na seção `System.Web` no `Web.Config`

```
<globalization uiCulture="pt-BR" culture="pt-BR" enableClientBasedCulture="true" requestEncoding="UTF-8" responseEncoding="UTF-8" fileEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

Campo datetime no cshtml

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Inicio, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 1):

Creio que minha resposta apontada por você esteja desatualizada. [Esta aqui deve resolver mais especificamente seu problema](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/60423/problema-de-data-com-globalize-js-e-jquery-validation-globalize-js-como-resolve/60432#60432). Para o caso específico do jQuery Validate e do Globalize, é preciso ter uma ordenação específica dos scripts.

Evite separar o *bundle* do Globalize do *bundle* do jQuery Validate. Evite também usar `@Html.EditorFor()` para campos de data. Use `@Html.TextBoxFor()` no lugar.

---

**EDIT**

Uso do `@Html.TextBoxFor()` para o caso de datas:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MinhaData, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "minha_classe_de_css"})
```

Comment: Cigano, eu estive utilizando o EditorFor porque este funcionou perfeitamente no Chrome, mas o mesmo não ocorreu no FireFox nem no IE. Com o TextBox, não estava funcionando em nenhum navegador. Vou verificar seu link

Comment: Realizei a implementação do tópico que você postou, mas o erro persiste. No log do Javascript não aparece nenhum erro, anteriormente aparecia algo relacionado a Globalize.Parse.

Comment: @Vinícius Agora pode ser a validação interna. Veja a edição que coloquei agora.

Comment: fiz conforme você indicou, mas continua trocando as datas no controller. Atualizei a pergunta com o campo Razor no cshtml.

Comment: Observando o valor da chave Request["Inicio"], vejo que o valor vem correto do html mas ele não é convertido corretamente para datetime.

Comment: Pode colocar na sua pergunta como o Globalize foi instalado?

Answer (score 0):

Creio que este erro esteja relacionado a cultura configurada na validação do jQuery.

Tenta adicionar o script `Scripts/cultures/Globalize.culture.pt-BR.js` ao bundle e depois adiciona esse script para sobrescrever a validação de data do jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
            Globalize.culture("pt-BR");
            return this.optional(element) || Globalize.parseDate(value) !== null;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Informações encontradas [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548816/mvc-4-date-culture-issue).

Comment: O script Globalize.culture.pt-BR.js não foi instalado junto com o Globalize, nem o Globalize.Validation.

Comment: Executou o `Install-Package jquery.Validation.Globalize` no Package Manager Console?

Comment: Sim... ele instalou o JQuery.Validation.Globalize.js mas não adicionou a pasta culture.

Comment: @Vinícius tenho o mesmo problema, você conseguiu resolver ?

Comment: @MatheusMiranda vou publicar a resposta

Comment: Olá @Vinícius, fiz um pequeno tutorial aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/227756/54019

Answer (score 0):

Vinícius sei que é complicado, fiz um pequeno tutorial aqui:

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/227756/54019

Quando você executa o comando `Install-Package jquery.Validation.Globalize`, não vem pacote completo. Você deve fazer isso manualmente.

No site [globalize](https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize) documentou:

> We do NOT embed any i18n data within our library. However, we make it
>   really easy to use. Read How to get and load CLDR JSON data for more
>   information on its usage.